# Layout (z-order?) bug when flagging questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, flagging

The default bottom part of the site overlaps the flagging reasons dialog.
I always have the latest Firefox version (27.0.1 as of this writing)

[image]

Comment: That is in fact an `overflow: hidden;` problem. Removing it for me makes it work and also doesn't break the layout in my recent-ish FF.

Comment: This also applies to the flag handling dialog (helpful/dedclined) with the left/right margins (I expect it's the same issue).

Comment: Is this firefox only, or have you observed it elsewhere?

Comment: @Shog9: Yes, it happens on Chromium too, on any page that doesn't have the `question-page` class on its `<body>` tag; see my answer below.

Comment: Related (likely the same issue): http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/z-index-issues-in-the-10k-tools-flag-queue?lq=1

Answer (score 5):

We do need the position:relative but I removed it on the mod & review pages. This way you won't have the bug anymore. A fix has been pushed, it'll be live after the next production build.

Comment: This is still an issue when flagging the last answer in the review queue

Answer (score 3):

For question pages (like this one), the workplace.SE style sheet currently includes the following workaround for this bug:

```
.question-page #content {
    z-index: auto;
    position: static;
}
```

which partially overrides the global default rule:

```
#content {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* extra attributes omitted for brevity */
}
```

Alas, review pages don't have the `question-page` class, so the workaround above is not applied, and so this bug still happens there.

Honestly, I'm not sure why the `z-index: 1` and `position: relative` attributes on the `#content` div are even needed, as disabling them entirely doesn't seem to cause any visible problems on any pages I can find.  Frankly, I suspect they're remnants of old CSS kluges related to the page header (and specifically to the two cutesy little "paperclip" ovals that extend down from the header to overlap the content) that have since been replaced by a better solution.  If so, my suggestion would be to simply eliminate them.

Ps. The `overflow: hidden` rule, however, *is* required on this site, since the content div here has visible border and background styles.  Without it, the content div won't establish a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context), and thus will not expand in height beyond its `min-height: 450px` to encompass the (floated) main bar and sidebar inside it.